# populating dataframe with youtube api

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, youtube-api

```
list2=['PewDiePie', 'jacksepticeye', 'iDubbbzTV', 'Markiplier','MarkiplierGAME',  'EminemMusic','EdSheeran', 'TaylorSwift', 'CNN', 'FoxNews', 'CBCNews', 'ABCNews', 'NBCNews', 'SkyNews', 'ESPN', 'UFC', 'BellatorMMA', 'NBA', 'KhanAcademy', 'Sentdex', 'CrashCourse', 'BigThink', 'DoctorMike']

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(list2)):
   request= youtube.channels().list(part='snippet',forUsername=list2[i])
   response= request.execute()
   print(response['items'][0]['snippet']['description'])#channel description
   channel_description= response['items'][0]['snippet']['description']
   request= youtube.channels().list(part='contentDetails',forUsername=list2[i])
   response= request.execute()
   print(response['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'])#upload_code
   upload_code = response['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
   request= youtube.playlistItems().list(part ='snippet',playlistId=upload_code ,maxResults=5) #retrieving videos
   response= request.execute()
   print(response['items'][0]['snippet']['description'])
   print(response['items'][0]['snippet']['title'])
   dfdict={
    "channel_title": list2[i],
    "channel_description": channel_description,
    "vid1_title":response['items'][0]['snippet']['title'],
    "vid1_description":response['items'][0]['snippet']['description'],

}
   df = df.assign(**dfdict)

print('/////////////////////////////////////')

df
```

I am trying to populate the dataframe "df" with the channel name, channel description, title and description of the first video pulled. so far with this method i have had no luck as it simply returns an empty dataframe. in the code i store the data in the dictionary "dfdict" then attempt to use the assign command to store it in the df.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Is your problem in the API stage (getting the correct data from YouTube) or in the Pandas stage (storing it in the dataframe)? Isolating it will make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: hi the problem i believe is with the dataframe. ive already set up my ai and have my api key

Comment: But are you getting the correct data back from YouTube? If so, you can probably remove the API-related code from your question and just put in a *sample* of the data you're trying to insert into a dataframe.